# ObservableCollection and threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` in my class. And further into my class I have a thread. From this thread I would like to add to my `ObservableCollection`. But I can't do this:

> *This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.*

Note that this is not happening from the UI thread, so i don't have access to the dispatcher.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JaredPar's approach is a valid one. Another approach which is worth considering is using a thread safe `ObservableCollection` instead of the built-in `ObservableCollection`. There's a few implementations out there, but [Sasha Barber's implementation](http://sachabarber.net/?p=418) and the [CLinq Continuous Collection class](http://www.codeplex.com/clinq) are some of the better ones in my opinion. Internally, these classes essentially use the approach outlined by JaredPar, but encapsulate it inside the collection class.

Comment: Personally I was not able to make it works with provided links. I needed to user JaredPas'a approach you mentioned.

Comment: Try the following link which provides a thread-safe solution that works from any thread and can be bound to via multiple UI threads : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Comment: The article you reference by AnthonyPaulO requires the Immutable Collections NuGet package and only works with .NET4.5. Is there anything similar around for .NET4.0?

Comment: This is the best one I found so far and it synchronizes external event handling. Still you have to pass the GUI thread's SynchronizationContext (ie. Dispatcher) https://github.com/CoryCharlton/CCSWE.Core/blob/master/src/Core/Collections/ObjectModel/SynchronizedObservableCollection%601.cs

Comment: Both of these links appear to be spam when I click on them.

Answer (score 16):

The best way to solve this is to pass the `Dispatcher` object to the start method of the background thread.

```
void DoBackgroundOperation(ObservableCollection<SomeType> col) {
  var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
  ThreadStart start = () => BackgroundStart(dispatcher, col);
  var t = new Thread(start);
  t.Start();
}

private static void BackgroundStart(
    Dispatcher dispatcher, 
    ObservableCollection<SomeType> col) {
  ...
  SomeType t = GetSomeTypeObject();
  Action del = () => col.Add(t);
  dispatcher.Invoke(del);
}
```

Now later on when you need to add to the collection you can use the UI `Dispatcher` object.

As @Reed pointed out, a more general solution is achieved by using `SynchronizationContext`.  Here's a functional style sample using `SynchronizationContext` to create a delegate responsible for adding new values.  This has the advantage of hiding both the collection and the threading model from the code creating the object.

```
void DoBackgroundOperation(ObservableCollection<SomeType> col) {
  var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  Action<SomeType> addFunc = (SomeType st) => context.Send(() => col.Add(st), null);
  ThreadStart start = () => BackgroundStart(addFunc);
  var t = new Thread(start);
  t.Start();
}

private static void BackgroundStart(Action<SomeType> addFunc) {
  ...
  SomeType t = GetSomeTypeObject();
  addFunc(t);
}
```

Comment: +1: Also, the same approach can be done using SynchronizationContext.Current instead of the dispatcher, if you don't want to take a WPF dependency (ie: you want to also use this code in Windows Forms).

Comment: @Reed, added a solution with `SynchronizationContext` that has a functional flavor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look at this tomorrow as it is 01:30AM here.

Comment: @JaredPar: If a collection will be used for a view-only WPF control and its backing store will be thread-safe for multiple readers, what are the pros and cons of having the UI thread process updates individually, versus having a collection raise a IObservableCollection "reset" event on the UI thread if the collection has been modified since the last such event was raised?  By my understanding, a "collection reset" event should cause any consumers of the collection to assume all items may have changed and act accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

In.Net 4.5, you can use the Thread-safe collections, ConcurrentDictionary, ConcurrentBag etc, whichever suits your needs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

Please consider reading also : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So