# Add Emails from imap download to listview async

Tags: wpf, email, listview, imap

I am using imap to show email headers in a listview, the way I have it working now, it waits until all the emails download and then populates the listview, how can I populate the listview as an email is loaded?

I tried to implement this answer [Wpf list async update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614125/wpf-list-async-update)
**but how do I get the imap email's as they download?**

**EDIT:** can you access each email in the mail collection as it downloads?, once I can do that, then I can add it to the listview using await

```
 public static MessageCollection GetMessagesForFolder(string name)
    {
        client.Folders.Inbox.StartIdling(); // And continue to listen for more.

        client.Folders.Inbox.OnNewMessagesArrived += Inbox_OnNewMessagesArrived;

        var lastDays = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-15);
        client.Folders[name].Messages.Download("SINCE " + lastDays.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy")); // Start the download process;
        return client.Folders[name].Messages;
    }


public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentFrame = contentFrame;

        foldersList.ItemsSource =  GetMessagesForFolder("INBOX");


    }
```

Comment: this would work if each email was downloaded separately - however, it comes as a list, so await doesn't help - how can I get the imap emails AS they download?

Comment: Break it into sublists?  Get 20 at a time?

Comment: how do I do that?