# How to make Observable collection work in C# Net Threads?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, thread-safety

I was trying to implement a loading icon in my WPF application (thru threading) but hit a Null Reference exceptions when I tried to add items into observable collection. I followed the following suggestion but it does not work: 
[How to make ObservableCollection thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108045/how-to-make-observablecollection-thread-safe)

In short:

This works:

```
private void Refresh() {
MTObservableCollection <someObject> someTable = new MTObservableCollection<someObject>();
someTable.Add(new someObject());
...
}
```

This does not work:

```
private void Refresh() 
{
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
    MTObservableCollection <someObject> someTable = new MTObservableCollection<someObject>();
    someTable.Add(new someObject()); //this line throws null reference for someTable;
});
...
}
```

The reason I used Task.Factory is because I want to put in a loading icon while this happen.

Comment: Looking at your code there really should not be any reason that you are receiving a null reference exception.  I think you are going to have to put more of your code out there in order to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Post NRE stack trace, please.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use MTObservableCollection.. Instead use BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization.