# WPF CollectionView Error: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection, collectionview

I'm overriding the behavior of `System.Windows.Data.CollectionView`. There's a method that is supposed to clear and re-fill `CollectionView.SourceCollection` (which is an `ObservableCollection<object>` in my case) from database. Exception thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute.

It's thrown exactly the second time this line is hit `SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);`.

(*commented lines describe my failed attempts to fix the problem*):

```
    //...
    public ObservableCollection<object> SourceObservableCollection { get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)SourceCollection; } }

    //<Part of Attempt7>
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(args);
        isCollectionChanging = false;
    }
    private bool isCollectionChanging = false;
    //</Part of Attempt7>
    //<Part of Attempt9>
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    //</Part of Attempt9>
    //<*async syntax is part of Attempt10*/>
    public async void RefreshSource()
    {
        SourceObservableCollection.Clear();

        // refreshSourceFunction retrieves data from Database
        IEnumerable result = refreshSourceFunction(/*parameters*/);

        ////Attempt1:
        foreach (object item in result)
        {
            SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        }

        ////Attempt2:
        //foreach (object item in result.OfType<object>().ToList())
        //{
        //    SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        //}

        ////Attempt3:
        //List<object> lstResult = result.OfType<object>().ToList();
        //foreach (object item in lstResult)
        //    SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);

        ////Attempt4:
        //List<object> lstResult2 = result.OfType<object>().ToList();
        //for (int x = 0; x < lstResult2.Count; x++)
        //{
        //    SourceObservableCollection.Add(lstResult2[x]);
        //}

        ////Attempt5:
        //IEnumerator enumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
        //while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        //{
        //    SourceObservableCollection.Add(enumerator.Current);
        //}

        ////Attempt6:
        //IEnumerator enumerator2 = result.GetEnumerator();
        //while (enumerator2.MoveNext())
        //{
        //    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        //    {
        //        SourceObservableCollection.Add(enumerator2.Current);
        //    });
        //}

        ////Attempt7:
        //foreach (object item in result)
        //{
        //    isCollectionChanging = true;
        //    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        //    {
        //        SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        //    }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
        //    while (isCollectionChanging) ;
        //}

        ////Attempt8:
        //foreach (object item in result)
        //{
        //    SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        //    Refresh();
        //}

        ////Attempt9:
        //foreach (object item in result)
        //{
        //    lock (_lock)
        //    {
        //        SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        //    }
        //}

        ////Attempt10:
        //await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => SourceObservableCollection.Clear());
        //IEnumerable result2 = await Task.Run(() => refreshSourceFunction(/*parameters*/));
        //foreach (object item in result2)
        //{
        //    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => SourceObservableCollection.Add(item));
        //}
    }
    //...
```

Exception `StackTrace` had only this:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)

However, debug call stack was:

> mscorlib.dll!System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource
>   resource) Unknown
>
> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()  Unknown
>
> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List.Enumerator.MoveNext()  Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.IndexedEnumerable.EnsureEnumerator() Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.IndexedEnumerable.EnsureCacheCurrent()   Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.IndexedEnumerable.Count.get()    Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.Count.get()    Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.AdjustCurrencyForAdd(int
>   index)    Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args) Unknown
>
> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(object
>   sender,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args) Unknown
>
> System.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)    Unknown
>
> System.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.InsertItem(int
>   index, System.__Canon item)   Unknown
>
> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Add(object
>   item) Unknown
>
> MyDll.dll!MyDll.MyNamespace.MyOverriddenCollectionView.RefreshSource() Line 105 C#

After observing debug stack trace, I became suspicious of `MS.Internal.Data.IndexedEnumerable` methods, especially after [observing it in ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/IndexedEnumerable.cs); as you see, it's not safe for multi-threaded use:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// for a collection implementing IEnumerable this offers
    /// optimistic indexer, i.e. this[int index] { get; }
    /// and cached Count/IsEmpty properties and IndexOf method,
    /// assuming that after an initial request to read item[N],
    /// the following indices will be a sequence for index N+1, N+2 etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This class is NOT safe for multi-threaded use.
    /// if the source collection implements IList or ICollection, the corresponding
    /// properties/methods will be used instead of the cached versions
    /// </remarks>
    internal class IndexedEnumerable : IEnumerable, IWeakEventListener
    {
    //...
```

However, I still couldn't figure out how to get around that, or even what exactly goes wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

*current .Net Framework version: 4.5*

Comment: Can it be caused by that `result` is still being populated (in the method `refreshSourceFunction`), and you start to iterate it through (`foreach`)?

Comment: I thought of that, but if this was the case, it should've been solved by `.ToList()` in any of the attempts 2, 3, or 4. And even without `.ToList()`, `result` was never modified. @kennyzx

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => // { // SourceObservableCollection.Add(item); // }, Try this as well lets see –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was actually in `ObservableCollection<T>` itself as it's NOT thread-safe. It seems that it was being read in the UI thread while it was still being modified, and the threading-related work-around(s) described in the question didn't work because `CollectionChanged` event was being raised anyway. Replacing the type `ObservableCollection<T>` with a thread-safe version [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288294/3602352) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you are iterating over a collection and try to modify it. Generally when you iterate over an collection it returns an IEnumerable which you can assume as a pointer sequentially moving forward. let say  you changed the collection then the iterator becomes invalid and framework throw invalid operation exception

For e.g (pseudo code)

```
Foreach(var item in collection)
{
    modify collection here; (Do some add , remove or clear operation)
}
```

In the above code the exception will be surely thrown

In order to handle this kind of scenario where you have to iterate over collection and wants to do some modify operation as well Use index

For e.g (Pseudo code)

```
for(int i=0; i< collection.count(); i++)
{
    // do anything here
}
```

Comment: As you see, the `IEnumerable` I'm iterating (`result`) was never modified.

Comment: the result is coming from SourceCollection is it?if it is the case you can use result.ToList() as well in Loop.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not; it comes from a database.

Comment: hmm. I got your point. What we can do in this scenario is delegate declaration. Pointing method to it.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        //    {
        //        SourceObservableCollection.Add(item);
        //    },  Try this as well lets see