# LINQ Where Clause always returns an empty list

Tags: c#, wpf, list, linq, generic-collections

Hopefully the title was clear enough.
My repository method looks like this :

```
public async Task<List<Model>> GetAllByCode(string code)
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return await ctx.Models.Where(m => m.Code.Equals(code)).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Out of the result of that method, I create an observable collection which I bind to the Combobox in the view.

```
Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>(await ModelRepository.GetAllByCode("code"));
```

But the ***ObservableCollection is always empty***. I can even see the results in Debugger (if I'm not mistaken, it's an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` collection). I'm 100% sure that database is okay, because when I use

```
return await ctx.Models.ToListAsync();
```

it returns all the rows from the database.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit :
The problem is in entity framework. I still haven't found a solution, but my context doesn't retrieve new data from the table, instead he always takes cached (I suppose) version even though I'm using a disposable context with every request.

*Still not answer to it though.*

Comment: Do you really have the value `code` in the `Code` field?

Comment: Sure there is any Model with `m.Code == "code"`? Or did you perhaps intend to write `ModelRepository.GetAllByCode(code)` instead of `ModelRepository.GetAllByCode("code")`?

Comment: Yes, I do have it. I double checked it, even for spelling errors.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Note that the comparison is done in the DB so it will be based on the collation you have set there which may or may not ignore case.

Comment: Database has been set to ignore cases.

Comment: Have you tried to trace the actual sql that  ef generates?

Comment: Also check for simple things that are not always obvious like trailing spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong it it, I think I found the error. EF Doesn't retrieve the last 3 entries I added (which are the entries with the code I'm looking for). I did manually enter it since this is just a testing phase.

Comment: I'm just querying a model object from his database table, and the model has  "Code" property in it. It's just a string. Regardless, I've figured it's an EntityFramework issue where the Context I'm using (even though it's disposable) is not returning any new data. I have no clue how to fix this. :/

Answer (score 0):

Equals can fail in LINQ to Entity if Code isn't a string, you can use `String.Compare()` or `(m.Code as string).Equals()` or this:

```cs
public async Task<List<Model>> GetAllByCode(string code)
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return await ctx.Models.Where(m => m.Code.ToLower() == code.ToLower()).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Or check your entries in table with this, step by step in debugger:

```cs
public async Task<List<Model>> GetAllByCode(string code)
{
    using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var all = await ctx.Models.ToListAsync();
        var result = all.Where(m => m.Code.Equals(code, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Please note that an ObservableCollection is not thread-safe.

Comment: I tried this, it's the same result. `result` variable holds an IEnumerable, but when I call `.ToList()` on it, and return it from the Repo, observable collection is still empty.

Comment: A observalbeCollection isn't thread safe. That's the problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108045/how-to-make-observablecollection-thread-safe
But boths snippeds works fine with async & await!

Comment: That might just be an answer, gonna recheck but I think I got it. Can you edit your answer with "Non-thread-safety" please.