# What type of queue to use?

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I have a static class called Monitor that includes a method LogToMonitor.

```
public static void LogToMonitor(MonitorDevice device, MonitorCategory category, MonitorType type, string msg)
```

It creates a MonitorEntry type and updates a property which does a property change to the UI and adds to an ObservableCollection.

```
 public ObservableCollection<MonitorEntry> MonitorEntries { get; }
```

I now have another thread that needs to LogToMonitor. This is going to cause issues having multiple calling threads.  I'm thinking I should have a Producer Consumer approach.

What type of collection should I use?

Should the Queue be a separate class which processes the calls and updates the UI?

Can I have multiple threads still call LogToMonitor method which puts them in the Queue?

Comment: What do you mean by "type" of queue? There are a couple `Queue` classes in .NET (generic and non-generic), but they all do the same thing (more or less). It sounds like you want something with additional functionality though, is that right?

Comment: At a minimum you only need to lock your LogToMonitor function when a producer calls it. Then, when you update your gui in the context of another thread, you do the usual ``InvokeRequired`` and ``Invoke`` stuff. If your drawing takes longer than you want your threads to spend on it, your queue would not be of much help. (Unless your producers produce at a low enough and maybe bursty rate).

Comment: My bad use of the word type, sorry.  I'll want to store my MonitorEntries in it.  Don't think I need addition functionality.

>>your producers produce at a low enough
yup, could be an issue, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BlockingCollection<T>` is what you are looking for probably. It's an implementation of the Producer-Consumer pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview

Comment: First try,  It was easier than it seemed to implement, but had to sniff though a bunch of examples to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection is not thread-safe so you can run into exceptions. Check the post of Robert Fraser, he has posted the code for a thread safe ObservableCollection. Use this instead of the standard implementation and should not have problems with multiple threads. [How to make ObservableCollection thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108045/how-to-make-observablecollection-thread-safe/29288294#29288294)