# Threading and creating ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I would like some explanation on how C# (WPF) works behind the code.
Situation (clearly hypothetical for the sake of simplicity):

On our UI thread, we create the Settings object. It has a variable:

```
public ObservableCollection<Something> collection;
```

From a different background thread, we call

```
try{
    Settings.Modify()
}
```

which then does the following:

```
Settings.Modify()
{
    collection = new ObservableCollection<Something>();
    collection.Add(...)
}
```

Now, of course this throws an exception at the Add function:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
> SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

But the collection = new ObservableCollection(); line executed. As far as I know, this new collection was created on the stack of the background thread. The WPF UI binds to this variable:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Settings.collection}"
```

In my understanding, the UI thread should not be able to access this collection anymore. What would happen if it tried, could it block the UI thread for some reason?

Oher question: Why did the compiler let me replace an object which clearly belongs on the UI thread with an other on the background thread, even though it knows I'm messing up when I tried to Add to that collection from another thread.

EDIT:
This problem's solution is already answered [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293246/observablecollection-and-threading):

What I am still curious about this: If the

```
collection = new ObservableCollection<Something>();
```

function is called alone, what would the UI thread do if it tried to access this collection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating an ObservableCollection in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104614/updating-an-observablecollection-in-a-separate-thread)

Comment: `new ObservableCollection` in another thread is a problem, don't do it in another thread. You can [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11625264/1997232) that part via dispatcher so it will be performed in UI thread.

Comment: It answers the question in the sense as what would be the correct solution. I have fixed the issues thanks to the linked question, but I am still curious about this:
If the collection = new ObservableCollection<Something>(); function is called alone, what would the UI thread do if it tried to access this collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't actually the `ObservableCollection<Something>` at all, it's the `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Settings.collection}"`.

`ObservableCollection` itself doesn't have any problem being accessed across multiple threads (as long as those threads are accessing it one at a time). The same goes for normal (non-`DependencyProperty`) properties- they don't inheritly belond to a single thread. The WPF binding system can (for the most part) handle changes to bound properties from other threads (provided you aren't using `DependencyProperty`). What *can't* handle changes from other threads, is `ItemsControl`.

Let's step through it, but first I have to make a few assumptions. First, I have to assume that `collection` is a actually a property, not a field (or is at least exposed via a property), since you can't bind to a field. Second, I'll have to assume that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is involved, probably implemented on the `Settings` class.

So stepping through:

1. In `Settings.Modify`, you execute `collection = new ObservableCollection<Something>();`. This successfully updates the property. The WPF binding system gets notified of this change (through the presumed `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) and handles the thread change for you. So `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` gets updated on the UI thread, via the binding, to the new value of `collection`.
2. `ItemsControl` takes this new `ObservableCollection` and creates a `CollectionView` which it uses as the data source for its items.
3. Back in `Settings.Modify`, you call `collection.Add(...)`. This successfully adds an item to the `ObservableCollection<Something>`, which triggers its `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event.
4. The `CollectionView` which the `ItemsControl` created, handles the `CollectionChanged` event, *but still on the other thread, where it was raised*. The `CollectionView`, as the exception says, doesn't "support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread". So it throws an exception. This exception *looks* like it's coming from `collection.Add`, but if you look in the call stack, you'll see it actually comes from many frames deeper. `collection.Add` is just the deepest level of *your* code that is involved.

When working with `ObservableCollection`s and multiple threads, I would advise creating the full collection on the background thread (if possible), before passing the full collection back to the UI thread for binding. In your example, you could create a local variable, add your items to that, then set it to your `collection` property once all the items are in place. Alternatively, you could pass individual items back to the UI thread to be added, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` or a `Task<Something>`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, that clears it up!